# Google Chrome not bolding words in HTML webpage

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, dreamweaver

So I'm using Dreamweaver and the bolded words appear on the DW editor but when I open the webpage in Chrome, I don't see the words bolded. Oh and the funny thing is that Safari and Firefox seem to display the bolded words while Chrome cannot. Which leads me to believe this is a Chrome-only issue. What's going on with my Chrome browser?

Here's a snippet of code that uses bold text:

```
<strong><br>
        <h4>Membership</h4>
    </strong>
    <p dir="ltr"><strong>Eligibility:</strong> All users must be <strong>18</strong> years of age or older and be eligible to legally work in the U.S.</p>      
    <p dir="ltr"><strong>Account:</strong> All information provided in your account must be accurate in order to achieve the best results from using our service. We are not liable for consequences that may result from fraudulent misrepresentation. </p>
    <p dir="ltr"><strong>Profile:</strong> Profile pictures must be appropriate for the professional atmosphere and clearly contain the person representing the corresponding profile only. Failure to comply will result in suspension of membership. </p>
    <strong>        <br>
```

This is what sets up the HTML styling:

```
<head>
    <!-- This needs to be on every HTML page -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>ProConnect</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="img/favicon-96x96.png">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/legal.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="" >
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/legal.css"/>
</head>
```

The CSS:

```
 .container{
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    }
    p{
        text-align: justify;
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the code you've got?  That will help substantially!

Comment: ....and we are supposed to give solution without seeing the markup / css??? :)

Comment: have you embedded external font in your project?

Comment: Added the necessary source code. I assumed you guys knew the general solution to this from experience. Keep in mind, this does not work on Chrome only. Other browsers display the bold styled text.

Comment: You probably just need to import the bold font weight for roboto. Try updating your import to this: <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

Comment: Just a tip - it's always good to add the relevant code to your questions, otherwise it's near impossible for us to help ;)

Comment: @btrballin check my answer solver your problem

Comment: Hey Tim, I changed the import to your suggestion and it mde the difference! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Great! I added the answer below to keep in line with the Stack Overflow format. Be sure to include the italic versions as well if you will need them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you import custom fonts, be sure to include all weights and styles that you will need. Normal font weight is usually 400, and bold is usually 700. The style sheet below would include pretty much everything you would need for the Roboto font.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this simple method to bold words
use `<b>` tag to bold words

just adding `<strong>` tag your word wont be bold you have too add this css rule to it `font-weight: bold;` only then it will work

```html
<b>bold word</b> normal text


<b><br>
        <h4>Membership</h4>
    </b>
    <p dir="ltr"><b>Eligibility:</b> All users must be <b>18</b> years of age or older and be eligible to legally work in the U.S.</p>      
    <p dir="ltr"><b>Account:</b> All information provided in your account must be accurate in order to achieve the best results from using our service. We are not liable for consequences that may result from fraudulent misrepresentation. </p>
    <p dir="ltr"><b>Profile:</b> Profile pictures must be appropriate for the professional atmosphere and clearly contain the person representing the corresponding profile only. Failure to comply will result in suspension of membership. </p>
    <b>        <br>
```

i use this method to bold in my website

Comment: Hey I tried replacing strong with b and it seems to display the text in bold for chrome now. I'm not sure if the tags were the issue or if it was changing the font reference to `<link href='fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700'; rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

Comment: Ok I changed the text font reference for another webpage to the 400,700 one and that was the game changer. It wasn't changing it from strong to b

Answer (score 1):

You want to add `<b></b>` tag to your HTML file instead of strong or you can do it by CSS also like this:

```
strong {
  font-weight: strong;
}
```

You can also keep your texts in normal way and just add some colours to look or more attractive or eye-catching:

```
strong {
  color: red;
}
```

Remember one thing I used CSS including strong tag because you have kept that word which you want to decorate in `<strong></strong>` tag.